# Выводит 'empty result'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Текст задачи:

> Напишите программу, которая принимает на вход список чисел в одной
> строке и выводит на экран в одну строку значения, которые встречаются
> в нём более одного раза.
>
> Для решения задачи может пригодиться метод sort списка.
>
> Выводимые числа не должны повторяться, порядок их вывода может быть
> произвольным.

Сам код:

```
s = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
l = len(s)
s.sort()
for i in range(0,l-1):
    if (s[i]==s[i+1] and s[i+1]!=s[i+2]):
        print(s[i+1], end=" ")
    else:
        i = i + 1
```

Выводит вместо ответа empty result. Почему он игнорирует print?

Comment: С чего ты взял, что игнорирует?

Answer (score 0):

начнем с того, что у вас вот тут очень жуткая ошибка

```
for i in range(0,l-1):
    if (s[i]==s[i+1] and s[i+1]!=s[i+2]):
```

потому что в случае, если друг за другом будут идти одинаковые элементы и условие `s[i]==s[i+1]` будет выполнено, то дальше будет проверено `s[i+1]!=s[i+2]`

и если одинаковые элементы находятся в конце списка, то будет обращение к `s[i+2]`, а учитывая, что `i` доходит до `len(s) - 2` включительно, то обращение будет к `s[len(s)]` - а это выход за диапазон и будет ошибка

> IndexError: list index out of range

что легко можно проверить введя `1 1`

на счет вывода ответа - ну так вроде когда находит одинаковые элементы - выводит, когда не находит - не выводит ничего, как вы и заложили в коде :)

А вообще можно обойтись и без сортировки :)

```
s = list(map(int, input().split()))
res = set(v for v in s if s.count(v) > 1)
```

и без множества

```
res = [s[i] for i in range(len(s)) if s[:i + 1].count(s[i]) == 2]
```

ну или покороче

```
res = [v for i, v in enumerate(s) if s[:i + 1].count(v) == 2]
```

или без `count()`:

```
from collections import Counter
res = [v for v, c in Counter(s).items() if c > 1]
```

или без преобразования в целые числа, зато с регулярками :)

```
import re
res = set(re.findall(r"(\d+)(?= .*\1)", input()))
```

P.S.

а вот как должен выглядеть ваш алгоритм:

```
for i in range(1, l):
    if s[i] == s[i - 1] and (i == l - 1 or s[i] != s[i + 1]):
        print(s[i], end=" ")
print()
```

Comment: cпасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: хочу еще доразобраться со своим кодом. поправила что вы указали. но выводит не все повторяющиеся элементы:

s = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
l = len(s)
s.sort()
if l < 2:
    print()
for i in range(0, l-2):
    if s[i] == s[i+1] and s[i+1] != s[i + 2]:
        print(s[i+1], end=" ")    
    if (i==l-2 and s[l-1] == s[l]):
            print(s[l], end=" ")
    else:
        i = i + 2

Comment: то что вы сейчас сделали называется "костыли", т.е. ошибки вы не исправили, а замели под ковер :) изначально надо править алгоритм, кроме того зачем-то добавили непонятную проверку на длину 2 - ЗАЧЕМ? - чтобы работал ваш алгоритм надо сравнивать элементы с предыдущим и последующим и выводить значение если оно равно предыдущему, но не равно последующему (ваша попытка в первоначальном примере), осталось только учесть граничные условия :)

Comment: проверка на длину - при длине 1 должно выводить ничего.
а в чем алгоритм неверен?
я прохожу по длине-2, дохожу до "границы", когда два элемента равны, а следующий после них им не равен, вывожу его, если нет, то просто + итерация и дальше пока в условии цикла не будет false.

Comment: добавил в ответе корректный код, только опять таки если введено много чисел и нет повторяющихся - ничего не будет выведено, а если вам нужно обязательно что-то вывести, то придется какую-то переменную просто добавить

Comment: спасибо большое.

Comment: Вообще все варианты решения через `.count` - это же сложность `O(n^2)`, такие решения на собеседовании не примут )